# How can I find the CPU resource utilization of a process and all its children

Tags: monitoring, cpu, sar, iostat

If I have a process that spawns child processes, is there a good way to get a single number representing the combined CPU use of that process and its children?  i.e is there a simple shell command available, or perhaps some info in /proc?

Target OS is either Centos or Ubuntu.

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12871375/1742825).

Comment: @Ramesh This answer includes a caveat that the parent process be "waiting for" the child processes.  What does this mean, that the parent has to block until children complete?  (i.e. it cannot work with child processes that are forked to run in the background?)

Answer (score 1):

Run a process this way:

```
time scriptname  # or
time command
```

It will report the sum of children plus parent

As soon as you add the word daemon, the picture changes.
top will show the approximate value, `top -p [pid]`  You can also read /proc[pid]/stat.utime and friends (utime, stime, cutime, cstime (children start with c) ) with C or perl or python.  Generally, once you get used to this data, you may discover that system time and user time become as important as total cpu time for performance evaluation.

`ps -p [pid] -o %cpu`  is not very informative - it just shows current amounts of cpu being used, not accumulated time.

Comment: Thanks Jim!  Am I correct that this approach requires that the process exit before any information is available?  (i.e. would this work for getting info on a daemon that never terminates?)

Comment: Yes, it requires the [scriptname command or whatever ] to complete.

Comment: Added more information about long running process monitoring.